# How to transform this SQL query to query with GROUP BY and HAVING?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

There're *products*, *products_filters*, *filters_values* tables in DB.
*products_filters* references to *products* table via product_id column which is a foreign key.
Also *products_filters* references to *filters_values* table via filter_value_id column which is also a foreign key
When user selects filters, SQL query which extracts all ids of suitable products is formed.
For example, chosen filters are:
Sex: Male, Female
Brand: Brand1, Brand2, Brand3

How it should work:
It needs to select all products which have filter Sex set to Male OR Female AND filter Brand set to Brand1 OR Brand2 OR Brand3. But products having matching only in one of the chosen filter category either Sex or Brand, **must not** be selected. It necessiraly to have matching in **all** selected categories.

I think SQL should look like this:

```
SELECT product_id FROM products_filters WHERE 
(filter_value_id = 1 OR filter_value_id = 2) 
AND 
(filter_value_id = 3 OR filter_value_id = 4 OR filter_value_id = 5)
```

Where 1 is Male, 2 is Female, 3 is Brand1, 4 is Brand2, 5 is Brand3.
But this query doesn't work.

In my previous question I was answered that GROUP BY and HAVING may help.

**Q: How can I transform SQL above with GROUP BY and HAVING?**

Comment: So did you check the manual out and brush up on GROUP BY and HAVING? And then give it a go??

Comment: your query will alvays return empty set, in one condition you should replace filter_value_id. You cannot expect any results where filter_value_id=1 AND filter_value_id=3, etc

Comment: Think about it. How can filter_value_id be more than one thing at the same time!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know that this isn't working and why it is so. I'm asking how to transform this using GROUP BY and HAVING

Comment: And I am asking if you have tried to do that yourself

Comment: sample data would help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
    drop table if exists t;
    create table t(id int ,gender varchar(1), brand varchar(1));
    
    insert into t values
    (1,'m',1),(1,'f',2),(1,'m',3),(2,'f',1),(2,'f',2),(2,'f',3),
    (3,'m',1),(4,'f',2);
```

Correlated sub queries with distinct

```
    select distinct id
    from t
    where
             (select count(distinct gender) from t t1 where gender in('m','f') and t1.id = t.id) = 2 and
             (select count(distinct brand)  from t t1 where brand in(1,2,3) and t1.id = t.id) = 3
    ;

+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_id
    FROM products_filters AS f1
    JOIN products_filters AS f2  USING(product_id)
    WHERE f1.filter_value_id IN (1,2)
      AND f2.filter_value_id IN (3,4,5)
```

(I don't think `GROUP BY...HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` is reasonable for this case.)

(The EAV schema design is a pain to deal with.)